# Python Kivy installation error MIX_INIT_MOD MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

MacOS: high sierra
Python: 3.6 (what I am using) and 2.7 (macOS own)
Cython: 0.26.1
Kivy: the newest master branch or the 1.10. zip via pip

first error in console while compiling:

```
 Running setup.py install for kivy ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/dw/3q9f4bpj3k9fwtg7k_kl0ws80000gn/T/pip-build-zj044_lx/kivy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/dw/3q9f4bpj3k9fwtg7k_kl0ws80000gn/T/pip-m8g5p5ha-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
```

Errorcode:

```
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/dw/3q9f4bpj3k9fwtg7k_kl0ws80000gn/T/pip-build-zj044_lx/kivy/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/dw/3q9f4bpj3k9fwtg7k_kl0ws80000gn/T/pip-m8g5p5ha-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/dw/3q9f4bpj3k9fwtg7k_kl0ws80000gn/T/pip-build-zj044_lx/kivy/
```

I tried to install the developer version from the master but go the "ZipFile is not a zip" error.
I used pip3 or pip3.6 don't know if that makes any differences.

Comment: Please post your code here. If it is too much please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I changed it, hope you can help me now. @progNewbie

Comment: How do you install kivy? Are you just running the setup.py? Where does the error appear? You are writing about an mix_init_mod error in the question description, where does this appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found out what was wrong. I just needed to download the zip file from the master branch out of GitHub. This was not possible with mobile data.